# Rails return to specific location with route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a link on a page that is for users who are not signed in yet. I want this link to redirect to the login_url, which upon logging in will redirect the user back to that page they were on.

Something like this would be great but I don't know how to route this.

Currently, I have a redirect_back helper but that only works on specific actions where you need to be signed in. This is just a link.

The login url is `/login` and I would like something like this:

```
("/login?return_to=" + @user.username)
```

for the link so when you click the link (say on the user jcl), it takes you to `/login?return_to=jcl`. Then after signing in with a POST request, it returns you to that user's page.

Is there specific routes or helpers that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a before_filter to save the url in the session and before login you redirect the user to the url in the session.

Comment: Thanks! I used a before_filter with `session[:return_to] = request.url` and it works great